# Получить список постов группы в одноклассниках

Tags: php, odnoklassniki-api, одноклассники

Как получить список постов групп одноклассников через их api? С возможностью потом выбрать кол. постов которое нужно выбрать и взять оттуда только id поста, либо кол. лайков и комментариев.
Есть идеи? Просто нормального api там нет. Парсить html не вариант.

Answer (score 1):

У них очень геморройный API и с ним ооочень тяжко работать.

Насколько я помню, все методы АПИ у них требуют авторизации (что во многих случаях оочень плохо).

По моему будет лучше подгружать страницу и тупо парсить HTML.

АПИ ОК - зло, как и сам ОК.

Comment: Это в курсе, права получил, только вот юзать что именно

Comment: @foozzi , раз доступ получен, то вот:

http://apiok.ru/wiki/display/api/discussions.getList+ru

но это, вроде бы, для пользователей. 

С группами никаких внятных методов нет.